# Retrofit,RxJava and Sqlite

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have retrieve data from Server using Retrofit and now I am trying to store with sqlite database

```
        WebserviceHandler.getImagePathSelectAl() 
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .flatMap(s -> WebserviceHandler.getCtbLeidSource())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(.................);
```

and response model class like

```
          public class ImagePathResponse {

            @SerializedName("Message")
            @Expose
            private String message;
            @SerializedName("HasColumns")
            @Expose
            private Integer hasColumns;
            @SerializedName("ErrorMessage")
            @Expose
            private String errorMessage;
            @SerializedName("ImagePath_insert")
            @Expose
            private List<ImagePath> imagePathInsert = null;
            @SerializedName("ImagePath_update")
            @Expose
            private List<ImagePath> imagePathUpdate = null;
```

and

```
       public class LeedSourceResponse { 
        @SerializedName("Message")
        @Expose
        private String message;
        @SerializedName("HasColumns")
        @Expose
        private Integer hasColumns;
        @SerializedName("ErrorMessage")
        @Expose
        private String errorMessage;
        @SerializedName("LeedSource_insert")
        @Expose
        private List<LeedSource> leedSourceInsert = null;
        @SerializedName("LeedSource_update")
        @Expose
        private List<LeedSource> leedSourceUpdate = null;
```

now i want to **insert and update sqlite db** in each response, how can achieve this. I am new to RxJava and RxAndroid

Answer (score 0):

You can check Rooms persistence library its a sql library for android[Rooms](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) , but in this case I would recommend you using [RealmDb](https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/) instead of sql, its much faster and would work perfectly if you want to save your date for every response.

Comment: currently i want in pure rx, any idea ?

Comment: i dont know what you mean but rx+realm is commonly used.